# sick_scan Launch error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to using ROS and am trying to use a Tim561 lidar with sick_scan. When I run the command below I obtain the following output error.

```
roslaunch sick_scan sick_tim_5xx.launch 

... logging to /home/austin/.ros/log/8adb6048-1c48-11ea-a1ae-b94bf9e35c82/roslaunch-austin-Precision-5520-5563.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://austin-Precision-5520:46695/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /sick_tim_5xx/cloud_topic: cloud
 * /sick_tim_5xx/frame_id: cloud
 * /sick_tim_5xx/hostname: 169.254.172.71
 * /sick_tim_5xx/intensity: True
 * /sick_tim_5xx/max_ang: 2.35619449
 * /sick_tim_5xx/min_ang: -2.35619449
 * /sick_tim_5xx/port: 2112
 * /sick_tim_5xx/range_max: 100.0
 * /sick_tim_5xx/scanner_type: sick_tim_5xx
 * /sick_tim_5xx/timelimit: 5
 * /sick_tim_5xx/use_binary_protocol: True

NODES
  /
    sick_tim_5xx (sick_scan/sick_generic_caller)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[sick_tim_5xx-1]: started with pid [5580]
[ INFO] [1576090913.600026808]: sick_generic_caller V. 001.003.020
[ INFO] [1576090913.600070064]: Program arguments: /home/austin/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_scan/sick_generic_caller
[ INFO] [1576090913.600079721]: Program arguments: __name:=sick_tim_5xx
[ INFO] [1576090913.600104200]: Program arguments: __log:=/home/austin/.ros/log/8adb6048-1c48-11ea-a1ae-b94bf9e35c82/sick_tim_5xx-1.log
[ INFO] [1576090913.608229162]: Found sopas_protocol_type param overwriting default protocol:
[ INFO] [1576090913.608254610]: Binary protocol activated
[ INFO] [1576090913.608266937]: Start initialising scanner [Ip: 169.254.172.71] [Port: 2112]
[ INFO] [1576090913.634351789]: Publishing laserscan-pointcloud2 to cloud
1576090913.6374 ERROR: Tcp::open: Failed to open TCP connection to 169.254.172.71, aborting.
[ INFO] [1576090913.639255645]: Parameter setting for <active_echo: 0>
[ INFO] [1576090913.839928764]: Sending  : <STX><STX><STX><STX><Len=0023>sMN SetAccessMode 0x03 0xf4 0x72 0x47 0x44 CRC:<0xb3>
1576090913.8401 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
[ERROR] [1576090919.908813399]: no answer received after 5000 ms. Maybe sopas mode is wrong.

[ INFO] [1576090919.908940549]: sendSOPASCommand: no full reply available for read after 5000 ms
[ INFO] [1576090919.909188489]: Receiving: <STX><ETX>
[ INFO] [1576090919.909267448]: SOPAS Communication -Error unexpected Sopas Answer for request <STX><STX><STX><STX><Len=0023>sMN SetAccessMode 0x03 0xf4 0x72 0x47 0x44 CRC:<0xb3>

[ INFO] [1576090919.909547112]: Sending  : <STX>sMN SetAccessMode 3 F4724744<ETX>
1576090919.9096 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
[ERROR] [1576090926.000694232]: no answer received after 5000 ms. Maybe sopas mode is wrong.

[ INFO] [1576090926.000826998]: sendSOPASCommand: no full reply available for read after 5000 ms
[ INFO] [1576090926.001042284]: Receiving: <STX><ETX>
[ INFO] [1576090926.001114041]: SOPAS Communication -Error unexpected Sopas Answer for request <STX>sMN SetAccessMode 3 F4724744<ETX>

[ERROR] [1576090926.001280456]: Error Access Mode
[ INFO] [1576090926.201903159]: Sending  : <STX>sWN EIHstCola 1<ETX>
1576090926.2020 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
[ERROR] [1576090932.263198941]: no answer received after 5000 ms. Maybe sopas mode is wrong.

[ INFO] [1576090932.263299494]: sendSOPASCommand: no full reply available for read after 5000 ms
[ INFO] [1576090932.263501296]: Receiving: <STX><ETX>
[ INFO] [1576090932.263565671]: SOPAS Communication -Error unexpected Sopas Answer for request <STX>sWN EIHstCola 1<ETX>

[ERROR] [1576090932.263724024]: Command or Error message not defined
[ INFO] [1576090932.263905386]: Failed to init scanner Error Code: 1
Waiting for timeout...
If the communication mode set in the scanner memory is different from that used by the driver, the scanner's communication mode is changed.
This requires a restart of the TCP-IP connection, which can extend the start time by up to 30 seconds. There are two ways to prevent this:
1. [Recommended] Set the communication mode with the SOPAS ET software to binary and save this setting in the scanner's EEPROM.
2. Use the parameter "use_binary_protocol" to overwrite the default settings of the driver.
[ INFO] [1576090932.264022750]: Start initialising scanner [Ip: 169.254.172.71] [Port: 2112]
[ WARN] [1576090932.264124339]: Disconnecting TCP-Connection.
sick_scan driver exiting.
[ INFO] [1576090932.319914563]: Publishing laserscan-pointcloud2 to cloud
1576090932.3225 ERROR: Tcp::open: Failed to open TCP connection to 169.254.172.71, aborting.
[ INFO] [1576090932.324637964]: Parameter setting for <active_echo: 0>
[ INFO] [1576090932.525201298]: Sending  : <STX><STX><STX><STX><Len=0023>sMN SetAccessMode 0x03 0xf4 0x72 0x47 0x44 CRC:<0xb3>
1576090932.5253 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
[ERROR] [1576090938.601870253]: no answer received after 5000 ms. Maybe sopas mode is wrong.

[ INFO] [1576090938.601967579]: sendSOPASCommand: no full reply available for read after 5000 ms
[ INFO] [1576090938.602142138]: Receiving: <STX><ETX>
[ INFO] [1576090938.602210681]: SOPAS Communication -Error unexpected Sopas Answer for request <STX><STX><STX><STX><Len=0023>sMN SetAccessMode 0x03 0xf4 0x72 0x47 0x44 CRC:<0xb3>

[ INFO] [1576090938.602536260]: Sending  : <STX>sMN SetAccessMode 3 F4724744<ETX>
1576090938.6026 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
[ERROR] [1576090944.703972546]: no answer received after 5000 ms. Maybe sopas mode is wrong.

[ INFO] [1576090944.704068575]: sendSOPASCommand: no full reply available for read after 5000 ms
[ INFO] [1576090944.704256181]: Receiving: <STX><ETX>
[ INFO] [1576090944.704316167]: SOPAS Communication -Error unexpected Sopas Answer for request <STX>sMN SetAccessMode 3 F4724744<ETX>

[ERROR] [1576090944.704397757]: Error Access Mode
[ INFO] [1576090944.904812464]: Sending  : <STX>sWN EIHstCola 1<ETX>
1576090944.9049 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
[ERROR] [1576090950.984822705]: no answer received after 5000 ms. Maybe sopas mode is wrong.

[ INFO] [1576090950.984927041]: sendSOPASCommand: no full reply available for read after 5000 ms
[ INFO] [1576090950.985132595]: Receiving: <STX><ETX>
[ INFO] [1576090950.985210738]: SOPAS Communication -Error unexpected Sopas Answer for request <STX>sWN EIHstCola 1<ETX>

[ERROR] [1576090950.985350173]: Command or Error message not defined
[ INFO] [1576090950.985489830]: Failed to init scanner Error Code: 1
Waiting for timeout...
If the communication mode set in the scanner memory is different from that used by the driver, the scanner's communication mode is changed.
This requires a restart of the TCP-IP connection, which can extend the start time by up to 30 seconds. There are two ways to prevent this:
1. [Recommended] Set the communication mode with the SOPAS ET software to binary and save this setting in the scanner's EEPROM.
2. Use the parameter "use_binary_protocol" to overwrite the default settings of the driver.
[ INFO] [1576090950.985579144]: Start initialising scanner [Ip: 169.254.172.71] [Port: 2112]
[ WARN] [1576090950.985638684]: Disconnecting TCP-Connection.
sick_scan driver exiting.
[ INFO] [1576090951.080715995]: Publishing laserscan-pointcloud2 to cloud
1576090951.0838 ERROR: Tcp::open: Failed to open TCP connection to 169.254.172.71, aborting.
[ INFO] [1576090951.085704559]: Parameter setting for <active_echo: 0>
[ INFO] [1576090951.. 286202931]: Sending  : <STX><STX><STX><STX><Len=0023>sMN SetAccessMode 0x03 0xf4 0x72 0x47 0x44 CRC:<0xb3>
1576090951.2863 Warning: Tcp::write: Failed to send data to socket.
```

After some research I found that it could be that I cant ping the LiDAR so I rand the following with the output.

```
austin@austin-Precision-5520:~/ros_catkin_ws$ nc -z -v -w5 $169.254.172.71 2112
nc: connect to 69.254.172.71 port 2112 (tcp) failed: Network is unreachable
```

How do I fix the connection error so my computer can communicate with the LiDAR?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339742/sick_scan-launch-error/) by [Aust](https://answers.ros.org/users/50084/aust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was a networking error with the LiDAR and the PC. The IP Address was slightly off and was found by using SOPAS to set the IP Address as the same as the computer and adjusting the last digit in the IP Address to a different value.

PC IP: 169.254.149.???

LiDAR IP: 169.254.149.XXX

After this, the error on the ubuntu side was that the wired connection was not connecting appropriately due to the IP error. It was also not staying connected so I then used the network manager to change IPv4 to a link-Local Only to allow for the connection to be secured. Now the node sick_tim_5xx.launch was able to be executed with no errors

---

Originally posted by [Aust](https://answers.ros.org/users/50084/aust/) with karma: 18 on 2019-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0